# Android Periodic sync not working on Oppo. I have to go to startup manager and allow app to run in background

Tags: android

Android periodic sync not working on oppo phones. I have to go to startup manager manually and ON app to run in background. Is there any way to do it programatically because user dont know to go to settings and change.

Comment: There is no way to enable it programmatically. You can fire an Intent to specific setting screen and let the user turn it ON . Also there is no way to check weather it is enable/disable.

Comment: But why periodic sync not work. It is android's own function to sync data periodically. Is there any other way to sync data periodically.

Comment: Provide more info with question. Which component you are using for syncing .